# More efficient palindrome code

Tags: javascript, dry, performance, palindrome

This is a code I used for the coderbyte challenge "Palindrome". The challenge is to return true if str is the same foward and backward(a palindrome). I got all possible points but I know my code is a little ugly. What would be a more efficient way to write this code. It looks like I am repeating myself and it seems like something that could maybe be written with a for loop.I also see how it could return true when its really false if there was a longer palindrome without the use of a for loop:

```
function Palindrome(str) { 
    var low=str.toLowerCase()
    var first = low.charAt(0);
    var last = low.charAt(low.length-1);
    var mid = low.charAt(1);
    var mid1 = low.charAt(low.length-2);


       if(first===last)
        if(mid===mid1)


        {
           return true    
        }
            else
        {
            return false    
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
        }
print(Palindrome(readline()));
```

Comment: First step: fix your indentation so that it's clear what's going on.

Comment: I don't know how you got more than a few points with that code, it seems that the tests are not comprehensive enough. The code works only for palindromes that are up to five characters. You need to check the entire string, not only the first two and last two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the string if it's a palindrome you just should compare it to its reversed version.
Say the word `hello` is not a palndrome because its reversed version `olleh` is not equal to it. But the word `eye` is a palindrome same as word `abba` because they're equal to their reversed versions.

Code example:

```
(function() {
    var reverseStr,
        isPalindrome,
        testStrings;

    reverseStr = function(str) {
        var chars = [];
        for(var i = str.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            chars.push(str[i]);
        }
        return chars.join('');
    };

    isPalindrome = function(str, ignoreCase) {
        if(ignoreCase) {
            str = str.toLowerCase();
        }
        return str === reverseStr(str);
    };

    testStrings = ['abba', 'hello', 'eye'];

    for(var i = 0, l = testStrings.length; i < l; i++) {
        var word = testStrings[i];
        console.log('Word "%s" is %sa palindrome',
            word,
            isPalindrome(word) ? '' : 'not ');
    }
})();
```

[**DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/3sPNW/)

Another way that could work faster is listed below. Here you don't receive a reversed string to compare but walking towards the middle of the string from its start and its end.

```
var isPalindrome = function(str, ignoreCase) {
    var length,
        last,
        halfLength,
        i;
    if(ignoreCase) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
    }
    length = str.length;
    last = length - 1;
    halfLength = Math.ceil(length / 2);
    for(i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) {
        if(str[i] !== str[last - i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

[**DEMO #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/pyYDu/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function Palindrome(str) { 
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.split(" ").join("");
    return str == str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

This is what I ended up with. Made sure the string was all lowercase so it  wouldn't read a potentially true parameter as false, got rid of the spaces, and then returned true/false based off whether or not the string was equal to it's reverse.

Comment: If the test case contains other special symbols like dashes, this will still fail. You could write a `replace` method to remove some other characters that aren’t letters—like this: `str = str.replace(/\s\-\'/g,'');` instead of `str = str.split(" ").join("");`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even easier way:

```
var isPalindrome = function(string) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    if(string.length===0){
    return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(string.length/2); i++) {
        var j = string.length-1-i;
        var character1 = string.charAt(i);
        var character2 = string.charAt(j);
        if (character1 !== character2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this palindrome coding challenge with a twist, you have to **replace all the non-alphanumeric characters**(punctuation, spaces and symbols) and of course change the string into lowercase. This is my solution.

```
 function palindrome(str) {

  var low = str.toLowerCase(); 
  var filteredStr = low.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, "");  
  var split = filteredStr.split("");
  var backward = split.reverse();
  var join = backward.join("");


  if (filteredStr === join) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

if you care about number of lines of code, here's smaller one

```
 function palindrome(str) {

  var low = str.toLowerCase(); 
  var filteredStr = low.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, "");  
  var backward = filteredStr.split("").reverse().join("");


  if (filteredStr === backward) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

the code is beginner friendly and self explanatory, but if you have any questions regarding the code, feel free to ask ;)